# Embedding of graph classes

Tags: graph-theory, computability-theory

Let $\mathfrak{G}$ be the class of all finite connected undirected graphs, $A,B \subseteq \mathfrak{G}$. Let $X[n]=\{G\in X :v(G)=n\}$, consider a function:
$$KE_n(A,B)=\max_{G\in A[n]}\min_{G\subseteq H,H\in B}|H|$$
I would like to know for what $A,B$ is the function $KE_n(A,B)$ computable? Obviously, this is true if $A$ and $B$ (or even just $B$) are finite. This is also true for some pairs of simple classes like $(A,COM)$, where $COM$ is a class of complete graphs. Are there more general criteria for the computability of this function?

Comment: How is the set $B$ given? The $\text{max}$ part is just finite and does not affect computability.

Comment: @LeechLattice , I need the machine to be able to recognize both $A$ and $B$. The fact that max does not affect computability is not entirely clear, because the machine needs to know which graphs from $A[n]$ it can take to test for the maximum.

Comment: The machine can just enumerate all $n$-vertex graphs to find graphs that can play the role for $G$, and it can also enumerate graphs by increasing order of vertices to find which graph can play the role of $H$.

Comment: @LeechLattice , what if for any $G \in A[n]$ there is no $H \in B$ such that $G$ embeds in $H$? How does the machine know when to stop?

Comment: This is not even a total function. For example, what if $A[n]$ is empty for some $n$?

Comment: This is not a problem because the domain of this function is decidable.

Comment: How about $A[n]=\emptyset$ if the $n$-th Turing machine halts with input $n$, and $A[n]$is not empty otherwise. Then even for $(A, COM)$, the domain is undecidable.

Comment: In one of the comments above, I wrote about the decidability of $A$ and $B$.